# DriveApi - Invalid DriveID

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm working with drive and I'm getting some problems, I only need to open an image from my drive folder, here is what I'm doing

```
public Drawable abrirBitmap(String Path) throws IOException {
        d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.amasar);
     /*   if (Path != "nada") {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Path);
            d = Drawable.createFromPath(Path);
        }*/


        DriveId FileID;
        FileID = DriveId.decodeFromString(Path);
        // [START open_file] Y se lo asignamos al imageView
        Task<DriveContents> openFileTask =
                getDriveResourceClient().openFile(FileID.asDriveFile(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        // [END open_file]
        // [START read_contents]
        openFileTask
                .continueWithTask(new Continuation<DriveContents, Task<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<DriveContents> task) throws Exception {
                        DriveContents contents = task.getResult();
                        // Process contents...
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // [START read_as_string]
                        //Leemos la imagen y la traemos a un bitmap
                        InputStream is = contents.getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);

                        // [END read_as_string]
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        // [START discard_contents]
                        Task<Void> discardTask = getDriveResourceClient().discardContents(contents);
                        // [END discard_contents]
                        return discardTask;
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Handle failure
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        Log.e("TAG", "Unable to read contents", e);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });


        return d;
    }
```

With this code I just open the path (driveid) of a file and put an image into it.

In my oncreate I just set my driveID to get the image

```
try {
       mImageView.setImageDrawable(abrirBitmap("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I have this output

> Invalid DriveID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=

the error points me here : `FileID = DriveId.decodeFromString(Path);`
and here: `mImageView.setImageDrawable(abrirBitmap("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="));`

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code. Put whatever that 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in a variable and log it. Now fetch it using 
[Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get). If you're not able to fetch it, it doesn't exist.